# Images is not rendering even after giving the correct directory path in Django. but works when I give incomplete directory

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-settings

So I have the image that I want to display in my page in a subdirectory 'media'.So I wrote this in my settings.py as recommended everywhere in the internet and documentation:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media/')
```

And when I load the page I get this error:

```
Not Found: /media/media/slider-1.jpg
[09/May/2023 19:31:11] "GET /media/media/slider-1.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 3943
```

why the path is `media/media` in my terminal eventhough the MEDIA_ROOT has only one `'media/'`

So I just wrote:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR)
```

and this worked perfectly eventhough the image is not inside the base directory but inside the subdirectory called 'media'

I'm curious how is this happening.

Comment: I think the problem is obviously the additional 'media/'. Even if I am not sure what MEDIA_URL is for, according to `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR)` works fine, I would say it's because BASE_DIR returns `/media/` and when you join it with 'media/' it creates '/media/media/...'

Comment: How do you use `MEDIA_URL` in your HTML templates?

Comment: Show corresponding model definition and template code.

Comment: @Matthias         {% for slides in sliders %}
                            <div class="header-slider-item">
                                <img src="{{ slides.image.url }}" alt="Slider Image" />